# Pill Shaped Composable in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am looking to achieve a design like below.

[image]

Looks like Material 3 doesn't have this as a native component.

Any idea on how this design can be achieved? Radio Button?

EDIT

Based on the answer by @Megh  I have modified some code to achieve the below.

```
@Composable
fun TabViewSample() {
    val selectedOption = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val backgroundColor = Color.Red.copy(0.2f)
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .widthIn(max = 600.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp, top = 28.dp)
            .background(backgroundColor, shape = RoundedCornerShape(25.dp))
            .wrapContentHeight(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {

        val list = listOf<String>("English", "Arabic")
        for (i in list.indices) {
            ProgressTabView(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                backgroundColor = if (selectedOption.value != i) {
                    Color.Transparent
                } else {
                    Color.Red
                },
                onClick = {
                    selectedOption.value = i
                },
                titleText = "English",
                textColor = Color.White
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ProgressTabView(
    modifier: Modifier,
    backgroundColor: Color,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    titleText: String,
    textColor: Color,
) {
    ElevatedButton(
        onClick = {
            onClick()
        },
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            containerColor = backgroundColor,
            contentColor = Color.White,
            disabledContainerColor = backgroundColor,
            disabledContentColor = Color.White
        ),
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(2.dp)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(25.dp))
    ) {
        Text(
            text = titleText,
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                .padding(8.dp),
            color = textColor,
            lineHeight = 16.sp,
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Well did it work?

Answer (score 3):

Try out this code:

```
@Composable
fun TabViewSample() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .widthIn(max = 600.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp, top = 28.dp)
            .background(Color.Red.copy(0.2f), shape = RoundedCornerShape(25.dp))
            .wrapContentHeight(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        ProgressTabView(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            backgroundColor = //your color,
            onClick = {
                //your onClick requirement
            },
            titleText = "Sample Text",
            textStyle = //your textStyle,
            textColor = //your color,
        )

        ProgressTabView(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            backgroundColor = //your color,
            onClick = {
                //your onClick requirement
            },
            titleText = "Sample Text",
            textStyle = //your textStyle,
            textColor = //your color,
        )
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun ProgressTabView(
    modifier: Modifier,
    backgroundColor: Color,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    titleText: String,
    textColor: Color,
    textStyle: androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(2.dp)
            .background(
                color = backgroundColor,
                RoundedCornerShape(25.dp)
            )
            .motionClickEvent {
                onClick()
            }
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(25.dp))
    ) {
        Text(
            text = titleText,
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.Center)
                .padding(8.dp),
            color = textColor,
            style = textStyle,
            lineHeight = 16.sp
        )
    }
}
```

Sample Output:

[image]